# change event doesn't work with span tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following input :

```
  <div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_date_naissance" name="casting_date_naissance">
      <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
        <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
      </span> 
  </div>
```

And this script :

```
 var dateinput = document.getElementById("casting_date_naissance");
dateinput.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  alert('a');
  console.log(dateinput);
});
```

Why when I execute this script the change event doesn't fire, and when I remove the

```
<span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
            <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
```

from the Html, the change event does fire.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that can help someone, I solved my problem, using this code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#casting_date_naissance').change(function (evt) {
 
          var dateinput = $('#casting_date_naissance').val();
          alert(dateinput);

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing your code on my side everything seems to be working as expected, with and without the span class.

Are you sure you want to use the on change event and not the on input event?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: how can I us input event in this case ?

Comment: The on change event will not execute until the focus of the html element changes, on input event will execute on each keypress associated with the input box